# To prove neccesary and sufficient condition for set $W$ to be a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The necessary and sufficient condition for a non - empty subset $W$ of a vector space $V(\Bbb F)$ to be a subspace of $V$ is

$a$,$b$ in $\Bbb F$ and $\alpha$ , $\beta$ in $W$  implies $a\alpha + b\beta$ in $W$.

I need to prove the postulates of vector space with this condition .Hints ?

Thanks

Comment: This is just running through the axioms. What are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: The problem is incorrectly posed. Your $a,b$ should be from the field of scalars $F$.

Comment: @Moya What should i prove or attempt to prove in this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The first axiom is to show that if $u,v \in W$, then $u+v \in W$. Since $F$ is a field, therefore $ 1 \in F$. From the property given to you, you can choose $a=b=1$ to get this axiom.

Now try to go with the remaining axioms by making appropriate choices.

Comment: You have assumed this condition to be true already

Comment: @K.Dutta isn't that what your question says?

Comment: Taking a=b=0 ,i see zero vector in W ,taking a=1 ,b=0 multiplicative closure is proved .Hence three conditions for a bubspace are satisfied .Not sure about my workings though